# Netsuite operation limitation

Tags: api, netsuite

I have read from the documentation for the [netsuite](/questions/tagged/netsuite) api that there's a limit on operations. The `Add` operation has a limit of only 400 operations even when *not* peak hours. I have googled it, but I couldn't find a way to increase the operation limit. Is it possible to increase the number of operations. Any solution, or link, etc would be helpful.

Comment: Is paying them an option? Or finding a different API?

Comment: I think your question should be, is there way to increase the limit on number of records per operation/request.

Comment: @vVinceth this is exactly what i meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the help topic `Understanding Web Services Governance` there is limitation on number of records in a request and NOT on number of `add` operations itself

As it clearly says

> The record limits provided in the following tables are on a per
>   request basis. There is NO limit to the number of requests that can be
>   sent within a given time period, only on the number of records sent in
>   an individual request.

You can always fire an another request with next set of 400 requests. If you are concerned that the requests are taking time and you really want to open parallel/concurrent requests there are two options

(1) you buy the SuiteCloud Plus license which would increase the number of parallel requests by allowing multiple concurrent users 10-30 (depending on number of SuiteCloud licenses you are allowed to purchase)

(2) Use RESTlet APIs which allows about 10 concurrent requests per user session, but would require to write SuiteScript in NetSuite account before you can access it via Https as web services.

If you are concerned about -

> is there way to increase the limit on number of records per
>   operation/request

Answer is NO

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you may consider is buying a SuiteCloud Plus license so you can submit simultaneous request. I still remember 1 license will have 10 queues wherein you can submit 10 simultaneous request, having this will increase your limit.

Answer (score 0):

In SuiteTalk Web Services there is an `AddList` operation which can take an array of 50 records to insert.  If the user has "concurrent web services user", then that is 10 concurrent `AddList` operations at once.